# Can not connect to node.js express webserver. (Error: Not found: /socket.io/)

Tags: node.js, websocket, svelte, sveltekit

I am having the following problem when hosting my sveltekit app. Thank you in advance.
When I use "node build" on my sveltekit app hosted on an digitalocean droplet I am getting the following error:
`GET http://???.??.???.???:3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OMjACu5 404 (Not Found)`
With npm run dev and npm run preview and even with node build at local, everything works fine.

The Ubuntu Terminal says:

```
Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000
Error: Not found: /socket.io/
    at resolve (file:///root/svelteSPA/build/server/index.js:3403:18)
    at resolve (file:///root/svelteSPA/build/server/index.js:3290:34)
    at options.hooks.handle (file:///root/svelteSPA/build/server/index.js:3525:59)
    at respond (file:///root/svelteSPA/build/server/index.js:3288:42)
server sveltekit (src\lib\server\index.js)
```

Client Code (src\lib\client\socketIo.js)::

```
(src\lib\client\socketIo.js):
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
        socket = io('http://localhost:3000/');
        console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV);
    } else {
        socket = io('http://???.??.???.???:3000/');
    }
```

Server Code (src\lib\server\server.js):

```
import { handler } from './../../../build/handler.js?';
import express from 'express';
import { createServer } from 'http';
import { Server } from 'socket.io';
import cors from 'cors';
const app = express();

app.use(handler);

app.use(
    cors({
        origin: '*',
        methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
        allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization']
    })
);

const server = createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server);
const port = 3000;

server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on ${port}`);
});
```

svelte.config.js:

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-node';

export default {
    kit: {
        adapter: adapter()
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to help myself.
I am now not using the node build command but instead I am starting the server.js file from src\lib\server\server.js itself. At least for my SPA that's working very well.

Thank you for your time.